# How you can capture the value of Cause By in a Hibernate PersistenceExceptionException in Quarkus

Tags: java, persistence, quarkus

Good morning, I am currently working with persistent java to consult a Stored Procedure in an Oracle DB, and I am catching the exceptions through a catch, however, I have a problem with the PersistenceException exception, which I need to read its caused By to do a conditional, so I currently have it and this is what the exception.message returns me:

```
    } catch (SQLException | PersistenceException e ) {
        log.info("Excepción SQL: "+ e.getMessage());
        if(e.getCause().getMessage().contains("ORA-01403")){
            response = mapping.setResponseError(request, ExceptionMessages.MSG062.name(), ExceptionMessages.MSG062.getMsgCode());
            log.info(SALIDA_MS + new Gson().toJson(response));
        }
        else {
            response = mapping.setResponseError(request, ExceptionMessages.MSG019.name(), ExceptionMessages.MSG019.getMsgCode());
            log.info(SALIDA_MS + new Gson().toJson(response));
        }
```

My Repository Class:

```
package com.tmve.account.repositoty.impl;

import com.tmve.account.beans.PostpaidAccount;
import com.tmve.account.repositoty.IFindPostpaidAccountByDocumentRepository;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;


import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.StoredProcedureQuery;
import java.util.List;

@Slf4j
@Singleton
public class FindPostpaidAccountByDocumentRepository implements IFindPostpaidAccountByDocumentRepository {

    @Inject
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<PostpaidAccount> getPostpaidAccount(String documentType, String documentNumber) {

        StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedureQuery=entityManager
                .createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("BuscarCuentasRolesxDocId");
        storedProcedureQuery.setParameter(1,documentNumber);
        storedProcedureQuery.setParameter(2,Integer.parseInt(documentType));

        storedProcedureQuery.execute();

        return (List<PostpaidAccount>) storedProcedureQuery.getResultList();
    }
}
```

My entity:

```
package com.tmve.account.beans;


import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Date;

@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
        @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
                name = PostpaidAccount.NAME_QUERY_BUSCAR_CUENTAS_ROLES_X_DOC_IDE,
                procedureName = "PERS.PKG_COMP_CUENTAS.BUSCAR_CUENTAS_ROLES_X_DOC_ID",
                resultClasses = {PostpaidAccount.class},
                parameters = {
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class),
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = Integer.class),
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, type = void.class),
                })
})
@Getter
@Entity
@ToString
public class PostpaidAccount {

    public static final String NAME_QUERY_BUSCAR_CUENTAS_ROLES_X_DOC_IDE=  "BuscarCuentasRolesxDocId";
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5853819176277617472L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "V_NUMERO_CUENTA")
    Long account;
    @Column(name = "V_NUM_CTA_PAGADORA")
    Long billingAccountNumber;
    @Column(name = "V_NUM_CTA_DIG_VERI")
    Long billingAccountNumberValidators;
    @Column(name = "V_TIPO_CUENTA")
    String accountType;
    @Column(name = "V_ESTADO")
    String accountStatus;
    @Column(name = "V_NOMBRE_ESTADO")
    String accountStatusDescription;
    @Column(name = "V_ID_PRODUCTO")
    Integer productoId;
    @Column(name = "NOMBRE_PRODUCTO")
    String productName;
    @Column(name = "FECHA_INICIO_PROD")
    Date customerSince;
    @Column(name = "V_TITULAR_CUENTA")
    String accountHolder;
    @Column(name = "V_TIPO_RELACION")
    String relationshipType;
    @Column(name = "V_PLATAF")
    int platformId;
    @Column(name = "V_IDENTIFICADOR")
    String identifier;
    @Column(name = "NOMBRE_AREA")
    String marketName;
}
```

This is what the e.getmessage() returns me:

```
Excepción SQL: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults
```

But I need to catch the cause to apply a conditional, specifically if it returns the code ORA-01403, as the exception is shown otherwise it will be caught:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:105)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:359)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:218)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:82)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:147)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler$1.run(VertxRequestHandler.java:93)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
        at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.execute(ProcedureCallImpl.java:624)
        at com.tmve.account.repositoty.impl.FindPostpaidAccountByDocumentRepository.getPostpaidAccount(FindPostpaidAccountByDocumentRepository.java:29)
        at com.tmve.account.service.impl.FindPostpaidAccountByDocumentService.getPostpaidAccountListByDocument(FindPostpaidAccountByDocumentService.java:43)
        at com.tmve.account.service.impl.FindPostpaidAccountByDocumentService_ClientProxy.getPostpaidAccountListByDocument(Unknown Source)
        at com.tmve.account.controller.FindPostpaidAccountByDocumentController.getPostpaidAccountListByDocument(FindPostpaidAccountByDocumentController.java:47)
        at com.tmve.account.controller.FindPostpaidAccountByDocumentController_Subclass.getPostpaidAccountListByDocument$$superforward1(Unknown Source)
        at com.tmve.account.controller.FindPostpaidAccountByDocumentController_Subclass$$function$$1.apply(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.QuarkusRestPathTemplateInterceptor.restMethodInvoke(QuarkusRestPathTemplateInterceptor.java:39)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.QuarkusRestPathTemplateInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:42)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:33)
        at com.tmve.account.controller.FindPostpaidAccountByDocumentController_Subclass.getPostpaidAccountListByDocument(Unknown Source)
        at com.tmve.account.controller.FindPostpaidAccountByDocumentController_ClientProxy.getPostpaidAccountListByDocument(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:660)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:524)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:474)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:476)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:434)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:408)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:69)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.convert(OutputsImpl.java:83)
        at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.<init>(OutputsImpl.java:60)
        at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureOutputsImpl.<init>(ProcedureOutputsImpl.java:34)
        at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.buildOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:418)
        at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:354)
        at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.outputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:634)
        at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.execute(ProcedureCallImpl.java:617)
        ... 44 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01403: No se ha encontrado ningún dato
ORA-06512: en "PERS.PKG_COMP_CUENTAS", línea 12122
ORA-01403: No se ha encontrado ningún dato
ORA-06512: en línea 1

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:630)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:564)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1231)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:772)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:299)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:512)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:159)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:1237)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeSQLStatement(OracleStatement.java:1820)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1472)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3761)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4136)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4279)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedntWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1014)
        at io.agroal.pool.wrapper.CallableStatementWrapper.execute(CallableStatementWrapper.java:1431)
        at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.<init>(OutputsImpl.java:56)
        ... 49 more
Caused by: Error : 1403, Position : 0, Sql = BEGIN PERS.PKG_COMP_CUENTAS.BUSCAR_CUENTAS_ROLES_X_DOC_ID(:1 ,:2 ,:3 ); END;, OriginalSql = {call PERS.PKG_COMP_CUENTAS.BUSCAR_CUENTAS_ROLES_X_DOC_ID(?,?,?)}, Error Msg = ORA-01403: No se ha encontrado ningún dato
ORA-06512: en "PERS.PKG_COMP_CUENTAS", línea 12122
ORA-01403: No se ha encontrado ningún dato
ORA-06512: en línea 1

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:637)
        ... 64 more
```

I need to capture oracle's own error code, that is, the one that comes in the following fragment:

**Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01403: No data found**

How can I do this?

**UPDATE 10/07/2023**

**SOLVED**

I managed to solve using the following line:

**e.getCause().getCause().getLocalizedMessage()**

```
catch (SQLException | PersistenceException e ) {
            log.info("Excepción SQL: "+ e.getCause().getCause().getLocalizedMessage());
            if(e.getCause().getCause().getLocalizedMessage().contains("ORA-01403")){
                response = mapping.setResponseError(request, ExceptionMessages.MSG062.name(), ExceptionMessages.MSG062.getMsgCode());
                log.info(SALIDA_MS + new Gson().toJson(response));
            }
            else {
                response = mapping.setResponseError(request, ExceptionMessages.MSG019.name(), ExceptionMessages.MSG019.getMsgCode());
                log.info(SALIDA_MS + new Gson().toJson(response));
            }
            return response;
```

[image]

However, is this a good practice?

Comment: You can use .getCause() to find the exception you are looking for and extract from the message of if exception concrete class has more info cast it to that type and explore from there.

Comment: I managed to solve it by making a command to cascade the cause

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in comments you can use `getCause()` to access the cause of the exception you're getting.

That being said, I wouldn't recommend catching such exceptions as:

1. `EntityManager`/`Session` are generally not considered safe to use anymore after an exception is thrown: the internal state is undetermined and they should be closed ASAP. There are a few "safe" exceptions such as `NoResultExcepton` but yours is not one of them. I mean it might work in practice, but if it does not (now or in a future upgrade) you're on your own.
2. Depending how you set up your transactions, the exception might have marked your transaction as "rollback only", in which case silencing the exception will be no use: your changes (if any) won't be persisted anyway.

Maybe investigate why the exception is being thrown by the Oracle driver and try to avoid it by implementing your stored procedure differently?

Comment: I managed to solve it by making a command to cascade the cause, however, would it be a good practice?